# Find the level segments up-to 7-levels in parent-child hierarchy

Tags: mysql, tree, parent-child, hierarchy, depth

**Parent-child table**

| id | introducer_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | Riya |
| 2 | 1 | Ramesh |
| 3 | 1 | Anand |
| 4 | 2 | Preety |
| 5 | 3 | Rakesh |

**Query to get members list when id = 1**

```
select  id AS memberid, name 
from (select * 
      from table_member 
      order by introducer_id, id) table_member_sorted,
     (select @pv := '1') initialisation 
where find_in_set(introducer_id, @pv) 
  and length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
```

**The above query displays output**

| member_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Ramesh |
| 3 | Anand |
| 4 | Preety |
| 5 | Rakesh |

**Now i also want to find the level of all the members**
**(i.e) i want the output as:**

| member_id | name | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Ramesh | 1 |
| 3 | Anand | 1 |
| 4 | Preety | 2 |
| 5 | Rakesh | 2 |

**How can i update my previous query to get the above output?**

**Note: Query to display maximum level upto 7**

**Thank You.**

Comment: `ORDER BY` in subquery `table_member_sorted` will be ignored.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: MySql version 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_tree (start_from INT)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
    CREATE TABLE tmp (member_id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
                      name VARCHAR(255),
                      level INT);
    INSERT INTO tmp SELECT id, name, 0
                    FROM test
                    WHERE id = start_from;
    REPEAT
        INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp SELECT test.id, test.name, tmp.level + 1
                               FROM test
                               JOIN tmp ON tmp.member_id = test.introducer_id;
    UNTIL !ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
    SELECT * FROM tmp;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=05bca7419e624830791d07845ef9e4bd)

---

> I have shared screenshot link of my sql version. snipboard.io/qbdB0A.jpg – AfreenB
>
> Your SQL server version is MariaDB 10.4.14. – Akina

For your server version use

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id member_id, name, 0 level
         FROM test
         WHERE id = @start_from 
       UNION ALL
         SELECT test.id, test.name, cte.level + 1
         FROM test
         JOIN cte ON cte.member_id = test.introducer_id 
      -- WHERE cte.level < 7 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=7bf21abf65aa7b87ecd7725414be952b)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this query isn't supporting my sql version, I have shared screenshot link of my sql version.   https://snipboard.io/qbdB0A.jpg

Comment: @AfreenB *this query isn't supporting my sql version* ??? that's YOUR words: *MySql version 5.6 – AfreenB*. The fiddle which works successfully uses MySQL version 5.6.50, and there is no constructions in it which may fail on any 5.6.x version. *I have shared screenshot link of my sql version.* :facepalm: Your SQL server version is MariaDB 10.4.14. My code works with it wothout problems: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&rdbms2=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=05bca7419e624830791d07845ef9e4bd But absolutely another, more effective, technique can be used in this DBMS.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, ill try executing it.

Comment: @AfreenB The query for your version added.

Comment: Both the queries executed successfully. In recursive query i also want to limit the  level to maximum 7.Please help me out to achieve this.

Comment: @AfreenB Added.